# Unserialize PHP using Microsoft SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

I am trying to import data from a mySQL database into Microsoft SQL because our company uses a mySQL website and MS-SQL Accounting/ERP system.

Anyways... Some of the fields in mySQL are "serialized". I am trying to determine how using sure SQL code I could unserialize and read the data into MS SQL. Is this possible, how?

One of the fields looks like this:

```
a: 9: {
    s: 15: "product_options";
    a: 2: {
        i: 719;
        s: 4: "2979";
        i: 718;
        s: 4: "2975";
    }
    s: 18: "unlimited_download";
    s: 1: "N";
    s: 7: "product";
    s: 37: "Champion Tagless Ringer Tee - T-Shirt";
    s: 10: "company_id";
    i: 0;
    s: 6: "is_edp";
    s: 1: "N";
    s: 12: "edp_shipping";
    s: 1: "N";
    s: 10: "base_price";
    d: 9.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375;
    s: 12: "stored_price";
    s: 1: "N";
    s: 21: "product_options_value";
    a: 2: {
        i: 0;
        a: 13: {
            s: 9: "option_id";
            s: 3: "719";
            s: 11: "option_type";
            s: 1: "S";
            s: 9: "inventory";
            s: 1: "Y";
            s: 11: "option_name";
            s: 5: "Color";
            s: 11: "option_text";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 11: "description";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 10: "inner_hint";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 17: "incorrect_message";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 8: "modifier";
            s: 5: "0.000";
            s: 13: "modifier_type";
            s: 1: "A";
            s: 8: "position";
            s: 2: "30";
            s: 12: "variant_name";
            s: 13: "White/Scarlet";
            s: 5: "value";
            s: 4: "2979";
        }
        i: 1;
        a: 13: {
            s: 9: "option_id";
            s: 3: "718";
            s: 11: "option_type";
            s: 1: "S";
            s: 9: "inventory";
            s: 1: "Y";
            s: 11: "option_name";
            s: 13: "Clothing Size";
            s: 11: "option_text";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 11: "description";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 10: "inner_hint";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 17: "incorrect_message";
            s: 0: "";
            s: 8: "modifier";
            s: 5: "0.000";
            s: 13: "modifier_type";
            s: 1: "A";
            s: 8: "position";
            s: 2: "20";
            s: 12: "variant_name";
            s: 6: "Medium";
            s: 5: "value";
            s: 4: "2975";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance anyone can provide on this.

Comment: This was done using PHP's `serialize()` method - I would use its counterpart, `unserialize()` for this

Comment: I know this but what to use in just Microsoft SQL code is there a serial and unserialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know this but what to use in just Microsoft SQL code is there a serial and unserialize?

I'm fairly sure there is no direct equivalent to PHP's `unserialize()` in MS SQL.

You would have to build it yourself - it would be far better to try let PHP handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation and decided to build my own T-SQL parser function... even though I consider it like beating a nail into a board with a screwdriver. I would recommend finding a different approach, but if this helps someone save time for something quick and dirty, I figure it could be useful.

[Unserialize PHP serialized data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955723/unserialize-php-serialized-data-in-t-sql)