# Stored Procedure in MySQL to extract text

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm not very familiar with MySQL 5.5, but i want to create a stored procedure that extracts variables from a text when calling it. Some help would be appreciated.
The table has a lot of entries and I want a procedure that extracts text from "booking_data" field in "wp_data1" table

The text in booking_data table looks like this: 
"a:11:{s:12:"gdlr-room-id";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"4351";}s:13:"gdlr-check-in";s:10:"2018-12-04";s:10:"gdlr-night";s:1:"1";s:14:"gdlr-check-out";s:10:"2018-12-05";s:17:"gdlr-checkin-hour";s:2:"12";s:16:"gdlr-checkin-min";s:2:"00";s:16:"gdlr-room-number";s:1:"1";s:17:"gdlr-adult-number";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}s:20:"gdlr-children-number";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}s:7:"service";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"4352";}s:14:"service-amount";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}}"

The variables I want to extract are: 
"gdlr-room-id";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"**4351**";}
"gdlr-check-in";s:10:"**2018-12-04**"
"gdlr-night";s:1:"**1**"
"gdlr-check-out";s:10:"**2018-12-05**"
. The values for the variables listed are in **bold**

after calling procedure, the result should look like this: 4351,2018-12-04,1,2018-12-05

Please help, thank you

Comment: That data looks like the result of PHP's `serialize()` function. It would be much simpler to return the whole blob to a calling PHP app, and `deserialize()` it, then you could access the individual elements easily.

Comment: Using SQL to parse semi-structured data like this is guaranteed to be delicate, error-prone work. If the format of the data ever changes, your SQL code will break, and it'll be more work to adapt it. It would be much better to use the tool that's intended for that job — `deserialize()`.

Comment: I need MySQL to do it because we are trying to integrate it with vb6 app for windows, I dont know how to call php function with vb6 code. Very new into this

Comment: Then you should store the data in a format that is easier to parse with vb6. My point is that it's hard to do this in SQL, because SQL is not the right tool.

Comment: i tried to extract the variables with vb6 function but it's very slow, i thought doing it with a stored procedure would be much faster. How can I call a php function and extract the result with vb6?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used VisualBasic.

Comment: Here's a similar question about parsing PHP data in Microsoft T-SQL. That's different from MySQL stored procedure language, but it demonstrates the approximate technique. **Warning:** View at your own discretion, not for the faint of heart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955723/unserialize-php-serialized-data-in-t-sql

Comment: thanks, im checking it